# JSP Save Parameter as a String

Tags: jsp

I am trying to save a parameter to a string variable in JSP but cannot figure out how to do it.

The request is working as it should and the data is being retrieved.

```
<%= request.getParameter("page") %>
```

But how can I save it as a string?

```
<% String temp = '<%= request.getParameter("page") %>'; %>
```

The above code doesn't work. :(

Comment: Any particular reason you're using scriptlets instead of JSP? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/139010

Comment: These scriptlets are a part of the examples we were shown in class.

Comment: Your teacher is cursing you and your classmates =\

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading that scriptlets are bad or out of date or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<% String  temp  =  request.getParameter("page");  %>` is enough to store the value...

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been going crazy trying to get this to work. :P Will accept as answer ASAP.